# meteor routes and autosubscribe

Tags: javascript, meteor, router

When viewing a "story", I want to be automatically subscribed to that story and change the subscribed story as I change pages.

This is what I got: It seems to work but multiple autosubscribe seems wrong?

```
route("stories/:storytitle/:storyID", function(storyTitle, storyID) {
  Session.set('storyID', storyID)
  Meteor.autosubscribe(function() {
    var storyID = Session.get('storyID');
    if (storyID)
      Meteor.subscribe("story", Session.get("storyID"), function() {
        Router.goto('story')
      });
  });
});

Template.story.data = function() {
  var storyID = Session.get('storyID');
  var story = Stories.findOne({
    _id: storyID
  })
  return story;
};
```

This seems to be more in line with what I'm looking for in general, but there's a ton of boilerplate. It also seems wrong to put a query into the route rather than just have it be in template helper.

```
route("stories/:storytitle/:storyID", function(storyTitle, storyID) {
  Session.set('storyID', storyID)
  var story = Stories.findOne({
    _id: storyID
  })
  if (story)
    Router.goto('story')
});

Meteor.autosubscribe(function() {
  var storyID = Session.get('storyID');
  if (storyID)
    Meteor.subscribe("story", Session.get("storyID"), function() {
      Router.goto('story')
    });
});

Template.story.data = function() {
  var storyID = Session.get('storyID');
  var story = Stories.findOne({
    _id: storyID
  })
  return story;
};
```

Are either of these the correct way to do it? How do I keep an auto subscription on a story, with it automatically changing subscriptions as I change pages?

Intuitively I would try this:

```
route("stories/:storytitle/:storyID", function(storyTitle, storyID) {
  Session.set('storyID', storyID)
  Router.goto('story')
});

Meteor.autosubscribe(function() {
  var storyID = Session.get('storyID');
  if (storyID)
    Meteor.subscribe("story", Session.get("storyID"), function() {
      Router.goto('story')
    });
});
```

This simply doesn't work. It would try to goto the story route before the story loads and throws a white screen/error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third approach is correct, although the second approach has it's benefits if you want to route somewhere else (e.g. 404) if the story is not found. Some notes:

1. To avoid the error on the third approach, just make sure (in your templates) to deal with the case when `findOne` doesn't return anything. You should expect to see this before the data has fully loaded from the server; the template will re-render when the data is ready.
2. There's nothing wrong with putting a query in your route in the second case, but be aware it will most likely return null initially. You'll want to wrap your code in a reactive context so that it re-executes when the data is ready. You might want to use my [reactive router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) to achieve this, or just copy the technique.

   This way you won't need to use the `onReady` callback in the subscription. (actually you shouldn't need to do this in either case).
3. The first technique is definitely not the right way to do it :)
4. If you do want to route to 404 if the story doesn't exist, you should wait until the data has loaded, see: https://github.com/tmeasday/unofficial-meteor-faq#how-do-i-know-when-my-subscription-is-ready-and-not-still-loading

Comment: I am using your reactive router, it's great, thanks for it :)

Comment: Thanks! I just added a 4th point that I forgot I wanted to say.